# why SQL queries not executed and tables not created spring boot crud rest api project with postgresql?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-13

I am running a spring boot crud rest api with postgresql and spring data jpa.

The application starts fine, but I am not getting any SQL executed - no tables are created, and it doesn't show me no errors on the console.
here is my pom.xml , repository, application-properties and entity files.

Pom.xml file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-api-sql</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest-api-sql</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
  @Repository
  public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{}
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private long id;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;
@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

public Employee() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Employee(int id, String firstname, String lastname) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

Application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rest-api-sql
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

Comment: Please read [ask].  We require that code and configuration listings be in the question (formatted as code) and not in images.

Comment: Can you share your _employeeRepository file...?

Comment: Thank you for replying , Please chack again i have added some code to clarify the issue

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 91. is [no longer supported or maintained](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: ok i will fix it thank you so much